# Undo everything in emacs

Tags: emacs

Is it possible to undo everything in an emacs buffer in just one step? I can do it step by step using `C-x u` but how can I do all steps just with one command?

Answer (score 5):

To undo back to the last time you saved the buffer, run `M-x revert-buffer RET yes RET`.